# amqp.node library, viewing error

Tags: node.js, amqp

I'm trying to use amqp.node library to connect to rabbit through SSL and according to the doc: http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/ssl.html
you should pass console.warn to the then callback.  In the project I just started work on (my first node project), we are using winston logger.  So how do I actually see the 
error because when I do,

```
var opts = { }; // my ssl info
amqplib.connect("ampws://{user}:{pass}@{host}:{port}", opts).then(function(err, conn) {
    if (err) {
        winstonLogger.error("err: " + err) // this just prints [object Object]
    }
}).then(null, console.warn);
```

I'm not sure how to map the console.warn to my actual logger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
amqplib.connect("ampws://{user}:{pass}@{host}:{port}", opts)
.then( ( conn ) => {
    // use the connection
})
.then( ( null, err ) => {
    winstonLogger.error("err: " + err.stack||err.message||err );
});
```

Comment: For some reason that does not work.  I also tried passing my logger to the `then` like `then(null, winstonLogger.debug)`

Comment: I may have misread the promise style you're using, so perhaps the .then callback should be: `.then( ( err, result ) => { if( err ) winstonLogger.debug( err ); })` ?

Comment: ya still no dice unfortunately. I do not get anything printed out.

Comment: @Crystal I re-read your question and the link to the amqp documentation, and I've rewritten my answer above; I think that should work for you now.